# Django Formset - Update Value in Views.py before saving

Tags: python, django, formset

I am trying to set a value on each form in the formset to a single value.
I am not sure how to accomplish this...  views.py function below:

Like:
`formset.idcst_cnt = id`

views.py

```
def customer_contacts(request, id):
    ContactFormSet = modelformset_factory(AppContactCnt, can_delete=True, fields=(
        'name_cnt', 'phone_cnt', 'email_cnt', 'note_cnt', 'receives_emails_cnt'), max_num=3, extra=3)
    formset = ContactFormSet(queryset=AppContactCnt.objects.filter(idcst_cnt=id), prefix='contact')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {'formset': formset}
        return render(request, 'customer_contacts.html', context=context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ContactFormSet(request.POST, prefix='contact')
        if formset.is_valid():
            print("we're updating contacts for " + str(id))
            # formset.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: in `if request.method == 'POST'` you can do `for form in formset`

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko, thanks a bunch! Can't believe I didn't think of that, duh!!

Comment: It happens :), I've just added the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `if request.method == 'POST'` you can do `for form in formset`

Comment: So I  know it's unrelated, and I can make a new question, but I'm running into this error now: `Cannot assign "1930": "AppContactCnt.idcst_cnt" must be a "AppCustomerCst" instance.`  any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like instead of integer id ```idcst_cnt=id```, you need to assign it to the instance of  AppCustomerCst with that id, something like this: ```idcst_cnt=AppCustomerCst.objects.get(id=id)```